# How to store blog categories in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to be able to find:

- what are the blog categories
- what are the post categories

The table definition what I have written at the moment is

```
CREATE TABLE blog_category_post (
   BlogID INT NOT NULL,
   CategoryID INT NOT NULL,
   PostID INT NOT NULL
)
```

I have heard of unique indexes that should be added to many-to-many tables, but i'm not sure how to add them in this case and if it is even the right approach.

Comment: Does the table referenced by "PostID" contain the information about the "post category"?

Comment: @WillP. It references to a table "Post", that contains post data like {PostID,UserID,PostEnteryDate,PostUpdateDate,PostTitle,PostContent,PostPublic,PostDeleted}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normalized schema, you would need two tables.

Assuming that you have shared taxonomy for blogs and posts (i. e. the same set of categories for both), that would be:

```
CREATE TABLE blog_category
        (
        blogId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES blog (id),
        categoryId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES category (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (blogId, categoryId)
        )


CREATE TABLE post_category
        (
        postId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES post (id),
        categoryId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES category (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (postId, categoryId)
        )
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` constraint implicitly creates a clustered `UNIQUE` index.